# Cast entity to dto

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

Just wondering the best way to convert a NestJS entity object to a DTO.

Lets say I have the following:

```
import { IsString, IsNumber, IsBoolean } from 'class-validator';
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';

export class PhotoSnippetDto {
  @IsNumber()
  readonly id: number;

  @IsString()
  readonly name: string;

  constructor(props) {
    Object.assign(this, props);
  }
}

export class Photo {

  @IsNumber()
  id: number;

  @IsString()
  name: string;

  @IsString()
  description: string;

  @IsString()
  filename: string;

  @IsNumber()
  views: number;

  @IsBoolean()
  isPublished: boolean;

  @Exclude()
  @IsString()
  excludedPropery: string;

  constructor(props) {
    Object.assign(this, props);
  }
}

@Controller()
export class AppController {

  @Get()
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  root(): PhotoSnippetDto {
    const photo = new Photo({
      id: 1,
      name: 'Photo 1',
      description: 'Photo 1 description',
      filename: 'photo.png',
      views: 10,
      isPublished: true,
      excludedPropery: 'Im excluded'
    });

    return new PhotoSnippetDto(photo);
  }

}
```

I was expecting the ClassSerializerInterceptor to serialize the photo object to the DTO and return something like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Photo 1'
}
```

But I'm getting a response containing all the properties still:

```
{
  id = 1,
  name = 'Photo 1',
  description = 'Photo 1 description',
  filename = 'file.png',
  views = 10,
  isPublished = true
}
```

I basically want to strip out all properties that are not defined in the DTO.

I know the ClassSerializerInterceptor works perfectly when using @Exclude(), I was just also expecting it to remove undefined properties also.

I'm curious as to the best way to go about this? I know I could do something like:

```
@Get('test')
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
test(): PhotoSnippetDto {
  const photo = new Photo({
    id: 1,
    name: 'Photo 1',
    description: 'Photo 1 description',
    filename: 'photo.png',
    views: 10,
    isPublished: true,
    excludedPropery: 'Im excluded'
  });
  const { id, name } = photo;
  return new PhotoSnippetDto({id, name});
}
```

But if I ever want to add another property to the response I'd have to do more than just add the new property to the class.. I'm wondering if there's a better 'Nest way' of doing it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One possible option is to mark your DTO object with the `@Exclude` and `@Expose` decorators and then do a conversion with `plainToClass`:

```
@Exclude()
export class PhotoSnippetDto {
   @Expose()
   @IsNumber()
   readonly id: number;

   @Expose()
   @IsString()
   readonly name: string;
}
```

Assuming you've decorated as above you can then do: `const dto = plainToClass(PhotoSnippetDto, photo);`

The resulting object is in the form you expect with only `id` and `name` showing up on the final object. If you decide later to expose more properties you can simply add them to your DTO and tag them with `@Expose`.

This approach also allows you to remove the constructor from your DTO that is using `Object.assign`

Comment: Thanks Jesse, I didn't realise @Exclude can be used class-wide. This is exactly what I was after!

Comment: @Lewsmith No problem! Glad I could help out. Thanks a lot for sharing the full implementation of the interceptor too that looks like a great solution! Might even steal it for a future Nest app :P

Comment: Why plainToClass though? We are not getting entities as raw from typeorm, wouldn't classToClass be a better in this case?

Answer (score 27):

So based on Jesse's awesome answer I ended up creating the DTO using @Exclude() and @Expose() to remove all but exposed properties:

```
import { IsString, IsEmail } from 'class-validator';
import { Exclude, Expose } from 'class-transformer';

@Exclude()
export class PhotoSnippetDto {
   @Expose()
   @IsNumber()
   readonly id: number;

   @Expose()
   @IsString()
   readonly name: string;
}
```

And then I created a generic transform interceptor that calls plainToclass to convert the object:

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

interface ClassType<T> {
    new(): T;
}

@Injectable()
export class TransformInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<Partial<T>, T> {

    constructor(private readonly classType: ClassType<T>) {}

    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, call$: Observable<Partial<T>>, ): Observable<T> {
        return call$.pipe(map(data => plainToClass(this.classType, data)));
    }
}
```

And then use this interceptor to transform the data to any type:

```
@Get('test')
@UseInterceptors(new TransformInterceptor(PhotoSnippetDto))
test(): PhotoSnippetDto {
  const photo = new Photo({
    id: 1,
    name: 'Photo 1',
    description: 'Photo 1 description',
    filename: 'photo.png',
    views: 10,
    isPublished: true,
    excludedPropery: 'Im excluded'
  });
  return photo;
}
```

Which gives me what I wanted:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Photo 1'
}
```

Definitely feels more nest-like! I can use the same interceptor where ever I need and to change the response I only ever need to change the DTOs.

Happy days.

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution but I am getting a run-time error: `Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TransformInterceptor (?). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in the ****Module context.`

Comment: quick question, this should work when we want to exclude the properties but what if we need additional properties in our DTO that are not there in entity. Also, what if I want to change the name ?

Answer (score 3):

For all type conversions, I've developed a library [metamorphosis-nestjs](https://github.com/fabioformosa/metamorphosis-nestjs) to ease conversions of objects.
It adds to NestJS the missing concept of a injectable conversion service for all conversions provided by your converters, early registered into the conversion service (like conversion service provided by Spring Framework in Java app).

So in your case:

1. ```
   npm install --save @fabio.formosa/metamorphosis-nest
   ```
2. ```
   import { MetamorphosisNestModule } from '@fabio.formosa/metamorphosis-nest';

   @Module({
     imports: [MetamorphosisModule.register()],
     ...
   }
   export class MyApp{ }
   ```
3. ```
   import { Convert, Converter } from '@fabio.formosa/metamorphosis';

   @Injectable()
   @Convert(Photo, PhotoSnippetDto )
   export default class PhotoToPhotoSnippetDtoConverter implements Converter<Photo, 
   PhotoSnippetDto> {

   public convert(source: Photo): PhotoSnippetDto {
     const target = new PhotoSnippetDto();
     target.id = source.id;
     target.name = source.name;
     return target;
    }
   }
   ```

Finally you can inject and use conversionService whatever you want:

```
 const photoSnippetDto = <PhotoSnippetDto> await this.convertionService.convert(photo, PhotoSnippetDto);
```

In relation to other answers of this question, you can use into your convert method plainToClass:

```
 @Injectable()
 @Convert(Photo, PhotoSnippetDto )
 export default class PhotoToPhotoSnippetDtoConverter implements Converter<Photo, PhotoSnippetDto> {

   public convert(source: Photo): PhotoSnippetDto {
     return plainToClass(PhotoSnippetDto, source);
   }
 }
```

and, if you want, you can call conversionService also within interceptor.

Get the README to find out examples and all benefits of [metamorphosis-nestjs](https://github.com/fabioformosa/metamorphosis-nestjs) .